# Adding records to a database without user action

Tags: java, database, text-files

I am working on a school project using java that involves using databases to keep record of clients.I am trying to read the users from a text file and add them to a database as specified by the teacher.My problem is that I need to add the records in to the database as the Frame opens ie.Without the user pressing a button.I'm not sure where to place the code to read from the file and add the data to the table(since so far we've only learned to type code under this: private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt).

[if this helps here is a screenshot of my frame:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31iIL.png)

Thanks
Ridhwaan

Comment: I don't know the full answer but private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) is an event which is called when a button is clicked. The frame which is opening will handle similar events as well and one of these will be an event that is called when the frame is created, this is where the code should be called from.

Answer (score 0):

There's two places you can put this code. The first place would be in the constructor of your Frame. Now, before you go and do this, know that loading or saving external data typically shouldn't be done in a class' constructor - I merely mention it here because it can work, not because it's good practice.

The second place (which is a much better place for this code) would be in a [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html), specifically in the `windowOpened(WindowEvent e)` method. I don't use NetBeans so I don't know how to add this listener through the IDE (though it should be possible), but in code it would be something like this:

```
public class MainActionFrame extends JFrame
{
    public MainActionFrame()
    {
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() 
        {
            // We also need to implement the rest of the WindowListener interface,
            // but the methods will probably just be empty. I'm only showing the
            // method that you will use for this question.

            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)
            {
                // database loading/saving code goes here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not kick this off from your `main` method? It's not something that should be part of your GUI code.